# Why isn't this duplicate closed?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I flagged this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82262/are-matter-waves-transverse-and-can-they-be-polarized) as a duplicate, the flag is marked as helpful. But it didn't get closed, I commented in chat and it's still open.

Comment: My guess is it's sitting in the review queue. Somebody did review it and agreed with you, hence the helpful flag, but not enough others reviewed it yet to close.

Comment: @tpg2114 Four days in the review queue?

Answer (score 3):

Close flags are marked as helpful the first time someone close votes. In this case, [one user close voted and three others didn't](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/25718) , so the flag was marked helpful even if the post didn't get closed, and the review item was dequeued due to the majority of do-not-close votes.

A "helpful" flag means that the flag had some worth and you should not be discouraged from raising flags in similar cases later on, even if the flag is not acted on. When it comes to close flags, if a user agrees with you, that usually means that the flag has some merit and should be marked helpful.

---

At first glance, they probably should be closed, but I'd like to see the opinions of other community members on the matter first given that at least three people feel that it is not a dupe.

Comment: Could a question be created to discuss non closed question? Everyone could post the question as answer, vote and discuss.

Comment: @jinawee It's usually best to discuss these in separate threads. Like this one.

Comment: I voted to leave the question open. Although polarisation was mentioned in your duplicate the discussion of it got a bit lost in the noise. I voted to leave the question open because I think it presents a good opportunity for a definitive answer. It's not obvious to me what the answer is. For a scalar particle the answer is obviously that the wave can't be polarised, but what about a fermion or vector boson?

Comment: @JohnRennie Good point (feel free to modify the question to clarify that, it would make it more obviously not a dupe). _This_ is one of the main reasons that we don't like too many questions per post :/